# Sinon.restore() does not work for inherited functions of namespaced classes

Tags: node.js, sinon

The Node AWS SDK has a namespace called `AWS` which contains a class called `SecretsManager`. `SecretsManager` inherits a function definition called `getSecretValue`.

I want to stub AWS Secret Manager's `getSecretValue` method with two different outcomes in two separate unit tests.

I have written two separate unit tests which work fine individually but faile when they are run together.

`sinon.restore()` is not working.

**Test code:**

```
const AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' );
const sinon = require( 'sinon' );
const { expect } = require( 'chai' );

describe( '67672805', () => {
    afterEach( () => {
        sinon.restore();
    } );
    it( 'should get secret value', async () => {
        const data = {
            SecretString: JSON.stringify( { publicKey: 'secretUsername', privateKey: 'secretPassword' } ),
        };
        const secretsManagerStub = {
            getSecretValue: sinon.stub().callsFake( ( params, callback ) => {
                callback( null, data );
            } ),
        };
        const SecretsManagerStub = sinon.stub( AWS, 'SecretsManager' ).returns( secretsManagerStub );
        const main = require( './main' );
        const { username, password } = await main( '1' );
        expect( username ).to.equal( 'secretUsername' );
        expect( password ).to.equal( 'secretPassword' );
        sinon.assert.calledOnce( SecretsManagerStub );
        sinon.assert.calledOnceWithExactly(
            secretsManagerStub.getSecretValue,
            {
                SecretId: '1',
            },
            sinon.match.func,
        );
    } );

    it( 'should not get secret value if there is an error with SecretsManager', async () => {
        const secretsManagerStub = {
            getSecretValue: sinon.stub().callsFake( ( params, callback ) => {
                const err = new Error( 'There was an error' );
                callback( err );
            } ),
        };
        const SecretsManagerStub = sinon.stub( AWS, 'SecretsManager' ).returns( secretsManagerStub );
        const main = require( './main' );
        const { username, password } = await main( '1' );
        expect( username ).to.not.equal( 'secretUsername' );
        expect( password ).to.not.equal( 'secretPassword' );
        sinon.assert.calledOnce( SecretsManagerStub );
        sinon.assert.calledOnceWithExactly(
            secretsManagerStub.getSecretValue,
            {
                SecretId: '1',
            },
            sinon.match.func,
        );
    } );
} );
```

**Driver code:**

```
const AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' );
const secretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager();

module.exports = async ( keyId ) => {
    return getSecret( keyId )
        .then( ( secret ) => {
            const username = secret.publicKey;
            const password = secret.privateKey;
            return { username, password };
        } )
        .catch( ( err ) => {
            console.error( err );
        } );
};

const getSecret = ( keyId ) => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        secretsManager.getSecretValue(
            {
                SecretId: keyId,
            },
            ( err, data ) => {
                if ( err ) {
                    reject( err );
                } else {
                    resolve( JSON.parse( data.SecretString ) );
                }
            },
        );
    } );
};
```

**Package.json:**

```
"aws-sdk": "2.894.0",
"chai": "4.3.4",
"sinon": "10.0.0"
```

**Expected**: sinon.restore() works

**Actual**: sinon.restore() does not reset correctly - the second unit test fails because it is using the same stub set up in the first unit test. If you reverse the test order, they fail the opposite way around. If you run the tests individually, they pass.

What's wrong with this? The docs suggest this should be fine.

Comment: What version of Sinon? You may also want to check out [this blog post](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/when-should-you-use-sinons-restore-and-reset-functions-bdbd39550a2f) although I can't tell if this is your issue or not.

Comment: @DaveNewton Good catch thank you, I have just added versions to the question

Answer (score 0):

@fatso83 has answered this on the Sinon github page: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/2376#issuecomment-847258040
and has taken the time to post a branch of this question and its solution here: https://github.com/fatso83/sinon-2376

This issue is caused by scope. Instead of declaring the AWS secrets manager at module scope at the top of `main.js`:

```
const AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' );
const secretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager(); // module scope
```

the stubbed item should instead be declared at function scope like this:

```
const getSecret = ( keyId ) => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        const secretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager() // function scope
        secretsManager.getSecretValue(
            {
                SecretId: keyId,
            },
            ( err, data ) => {
                if ( err ) {
                    reject( err );
                } else {
                    resolve( JSON.parse( data.SecretString ) );
                }
            },
        );
```

This causes the tests to pass, because the module scoped instance of AWS Secrets Manager is not preserved across invocations of the test (it is instead replaced by new function scoped instances each time the function is invoked).

**TLDR: Do not use SinonJS to stub module-scope dependencies**.

Full credit and thanks to @fatso83